# Speed up changing of font

Tags: android, performance, fonts

Is there any way to speed up the loading of fonts as when my activities loads slower than before since i have implemented my code for changing the fonts? i change the fonts for every activity in my app and use 3 different fonts. i have my fonts on the assets folder. a sample of my code is:

```
Typeface fontTitle;
static final String fTitle = "MStiffHeiHK-UltraBold.otf";

fontTitle = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fTitle);  
txTitle.setTypeface(fontTitle);
```

and so on...
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a class which handles your fonts and then have a methode like following in it:

```
public static Typeface getFont(Context context) {
    if(mFont != null) {
        return mFont;
    } else {
        mFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fTitle);
    }
}
```

Your mFont should be static.

For minimal performance boost you should make the methode finale, but besides this I don't think you can improve the speed much.